# Get starting point of Bezier Path in Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, path, core-graphics, bezier, cgpoint

I've been searching and I can't find the answer.  I would like to get the starting point of a bezier path already in the view.  I tried using the bounds, but that seems to get the 0,0 of a box around the path.  currentpoint seems to be the last point of the curve.  Can I move the currentpoint within the path?  Is there an easier way of getting the starting point other than storing it in an array when the path is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CGPathApply()` function to iterate over all elements in your path and specify a custom function that should be called for each element. It's like a `for` loop for Core Graphics paths. It's not possible to tell the function to just iterate over the first element in the path so you'll have to manually check for the first run of the `CGPathApplierFunction` and store the info about the then-current path element in an ivar.